# Test if there is a route between 2 nodes in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I know there are already similar questions, but I would like my searching method to be evaluated. I used a DFS algorithm to find out whether or not there is a route between the two nodes. Here is my code, and I would like to know the if there is a test-case in which my code would fail with the result.

```
public boolean routeExists(Node start, Node end) {
    Set<Node> visited = new HashSet<>();
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();

    visited.add(start);
    stack.push(start);

    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = stack.pop();

        if(current.getValue() == end.getValue()) {
            return true;
        }

        for(Node adj : current.getAdjacent()) {
            // keep track of visited nodes
            if(!visited.contains(adj)) {
                stack.push(adj);
                visited.add(adj);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have made an EDIT, now the code keeps track of the visited nodes, and does not expand them if they have been visited in the past. I believe this now should work.

Comment: You need to add some kind of circle detection.

Comment: You're using BFS, not DFS

Comment: If your graph contains a cycle (or if your edges are "bidirectional", i.e. if u is in v.getAdjacent() then v is also in u.getAdjacent()), then this function might loop forever.  If OTOH your graph is a forest (collection of trees), it will terminate with the correct answer.

Comment: I made an edit. The code now keeps track of the visited nodes.

Answer (score 4):

This code will go into an infinite loop for many input graphs.

Consider finding a route from A to B when the edges are:

```
A->B
A->C
C->A
```

Your code will first push B on the list, then push C, then visit C and push A on the list, and then repeat until a stack overflow occurs.

If you compare with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode)

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v as discovered
3      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5              recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

you will see that you are missing the test to check that the new vertices have not already been discovered.

Comment: OK, I added the keeping track of visited nodes so they dont get expanded multiple times. Is this now OK? There is an edit in the original question.

Comment: That looks much better to me, although it wouldn't hurt to write some unit tests just in case...